# How to read GDPR Data Request from a Shopify Custom App

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

When I create a [Custom App](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/app-types/custom-apps) within a store, one of the Admin API access scopes we can give access to is View GDPR data requests (read_gdpr_data_request)

What does this scope give access to? I can't find any Admin API that requires this scope access. I'd like to query GDPR Data Request with my custom app but I can't actually find how to do it.

I've found the docs on [Mandatory Webhooks](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/webhooks/configuration/mandatory-webhooks) to get Webhooks of GDPR requests, but this applies only to public apps, not custom apps. I cannot manually setup those Webhooks in the partner dashboard, custom apps are configured directly into the store where it is setup.